# Receiver in expresseion is a garbage value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, debugging, code-analysis

I am developing an iPhone app and are using xCode to do "Build and analyze". I get the message "Receiver in expresseion is a garbage value" pointing to the line of the return-row in my bode below:

```
-(UIColor*)getLevelColor{
UIColor* tempCol;

if (level==4) {
    tempCol= [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.39f green:0.82f blue:0.32f alpha:1.0f];
}else if (level==5) {
    tempCol= [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.61f green:0.68f blue:0.83f alpha:1.0f];
}else if (level==6) {
    tempCol= [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.90f green:0.68f blue:0.99f alpha:1.0f];
}else if (level==7) {
    tempCol= [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.68f green:0.97f blue:0.99f alpha:1.0f];
}

return [tempCol autorelease];
}
```

How come I get this and how do I fix it so I don't get the message?

Thanks in advance!

Niklas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that the compiler sees that there is a code path which returns an uninitialized value and gives you the news: `tempCol` is an uninitialized value unless `level` is anything else than 4,5,6 or 7. If you are sure that `level` will never be anything than 4,5,6 or 7 then add a `else { return 0; }` to the end of your if-ladder.

PS: You should use a `switch(){}` statement if you have to compare against a series of constant values, this is often faster and easier to maintain (IMHO). Alternatively, you could place the RGBA values in an array which you index with `level`.

(Disclaimer: I don't do Objective-C. Nobody should do it)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that creating an array and indexing with levels is a nice solution and it solves the problem if the reason is as you explained, which it should be. P.S. Well, if you want to develop for iPhone, I guess Objective-C is the only option D.S. /Niklas (normally a Java-guy...).

Comment: Objective-C is a wonderful language :) I disagree with your disclaimer.